# How to check if a file exist in metro app without try catch

Tags: microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have 5 limited numbers of file in Database and I want to check weather the name of file I want Exists or Not but without using an Exception handler.

Code Known till now

```
    try{
var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var file = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("data.txt");
}catch(Exception ex){
//file doesnot exist
}
```

But without this is there any way. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a work around essentially will not work for large amount of files and will also be a memory wastage in such case. Still Here's the Code

```
var files = await localFolder.GetFilesAsync();
```

Now you can loop through and check File Name for a particular file from the list.